# Ignore some updates android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, sdk

The following message is displayed when I want to update Android Studio

[image: IDE update]

***I don't want*** Android *5.0, 5.1 and 6.0* to be updated and ***only*** Android *7.1.1, 8.1 and 10.0* to be updated. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Ignore update and update Android SDK components manually from Tools | SDK Manager or Settings(Preferences) | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Android SDK.

See [Update your tools with the SDK Manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#sdk-manager).