# Update Android Studio from a specific version to a specific version

Tags: java, android, android-studio, updates

I was using Android Studio version 3.5.1

and I left the computer turned off for a while

and after I turned on the computer and ran Android Studio, a message appeared to update to version 4.0

but the stable versions before 4.0 are 3.5.2, 3.5.3, 3.6, 3.6.1, 3.6.2, 3.6.3 then 4.0

what I mean is, if I was using my computer and Android Studio all the time between 3.5.1 and 4.0, 
 I will be able to update gradually to each version in an automatic way I mean as a response to the message of update that appears automatically when every stable version is released

 and I will be able to update other components that appear like Emulator, gradle, and gradle plugin and .... I don't know if there something else (I am new in Android Development :)

Now, how can I do that, I want to update to every version after 3.5.1, update to 3.5.2 then update to 3.5.3 then 3.6 then .... then 4.0

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62358680/ignore-some-updates-android-studio) but I did not understand what to do

thank you very much

Hello @yacinerezgui

 Do you have answer

Answer (score 2):

Referring to this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49597121/13826785)

You can go to this link [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) and download the version you want and just run the installer again. It should prompt you to uninstall any other versions and you can follow the installation guide.

**Edit**
I reread your question again, you **do not need** to install every version of Android Studio in order for Android Studio 4.0 to work along with the emulator and other tools. You just may need to update other plugins if you run into errors but that should not be a problem.

Comment: Hello, @codearn19 I want that to be like what we do in automatic update but in automatic update there is something happen in the background, I want to do what is needed manually and what is needed automatically to achieve that

Comment: Hello, @codearn19 I want that to be like what we do in automatic update but in automatic update there is something happen in the background, I want to do what is needed manually and what is needed automatically to achieve that updating to the direct next version and do that in every update to every direct next version until I reach version 4.0

Comment: If you have Android Studio 4.0 already installed, you should see a message that says Gradle is ready to update or something like that. You do not need to do anything manually. The Gradle will automatically update to 4.0 when it says Gradle is ready to update for you along with updating the others from the Event Log

Comment: If you want to do it manually follow the first part of the answer

Comment: what I want is not working with the emulator or other tools I was just describing the update and what was happening with me during development in Android Studio

Comment: So do you want to update Android Studio itself or the SDK as in the link you posted?

Comment: I do not know, what I know that updating an Android Studio from version to version update what is necessary to that update